# While/ Do While loops in Java

Tags: java, random, parameters, while-loop, return

Here is my problem:

A student has decided to celebrate the start of Thanksgiving 
break a tad early by getting a bit smashed.

Her home is at corner 0 on Main Street, and the Jail is at corner 10 on Main 
Street. The student starts at corner 5, and wanders one corner to the left or to 
the right with probability 0.5 for each; she repeats the process until arriving 
safely at home or landing in jail. That is, at each corner, the drunk student has 
a 50-50 probability of staggering left or right, to the next higher-numbered or 
next lower-numbered corner.

Write a method named drunkWalk() using a while or a do-while loop that 
simulates the drunk student’s walk; your method should return with a single 
integer that both indicates how many steps were taken and whether the 
student landed in jail or at home. You can do this if you return the number of 
steps taken as a negative number if the person lands in jail, and as a positive 
number if the person ends up at home. You should not print out each step taken 
in your ﬁnal version of the method, though you might want to do this while 
you are debugging.

Once you have your method working, have your main program call upon 
your drunkWalk() method N times (where N is a ﬁnal variable). Finally, have 
it calculate and print the average number of steps that the student took for one 
trip. Here’s what your program might look like in action, with N equal to 5:

```
Here we go again... time for a walk! <br/>
Took 37 steps, and <br/>
Landed at HOME<br/>

Here we go again... time for a walk!<br/>    
Took 19 steps, and <br/>
Landed in JAIL<br/>

Here we go again... time for a walk!<br/>
Took 13 steps, and <br/>
Landed in JAIL<br/>

Here we go again... time for a walk! <br/>
Took 25 steps, and <br/>
Landed in JAIL<br/>

Here we go again... time for a walk!<br/>
Took 15 steps, and <br/>
Landed at HOME<br/>

Average # of steps equals 25.4<br/>
```

Here is my code: It compiles but I get no output. I think my code is overcomplicated, but I don't know how to simplify it:

```
class Drunk     
{

// When this code runs, nothing prints out????

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int home = 0; 
    int jail = 10;  

    final int N = 5; 
    int sum = 0;

    int a = drunkWalk(N); 
    sum = sum + a; 

    //System.out.println ("Average # of steps equals" + " " + (a/sum));

  }

  static int drunkWalk(int x)
  {
    int steps; // steps is the number of steps taken by the student
    int total=5;  // total is the starting point of the student (at corner 5)

    while (x > 0); 
    {   
      do 
      { 
        steps = (int) (Math.random() * (10 +  10) - 10); 
        total += steps;
        x = x-1;
      } while (total != 0 || total != 10);
    }

    if (total == 0) 
    {
      System.out.println("Here we go again... time for a walk!");
      System.out.println("Took" + " " + steps + "steps, and");
      System.out.println ("Landed at HOME"); 
    }

    if (total == 10) 
    { 
      System.out.println("Here we go again... time for a walk!");
      System.out.println("Took" + " " + steps + "steps, and");
      System.out.println ("Landed in JAIL"); 
    }

    return steps; // Need to figure out how to add up ALL the steps
  }
```

Please help!

Comment: Format your code nicely.

Comment: don't put semi colons after control statement conditions.  while (x > 0);/* the while loop just ended*/{ /*stuff you think it is in the while loop but it's not.*/}

Comment: The comment "format your code nicely" is not something to be shrugged off. In situations like this, taking care about aligning your opening and closing braces, etc, will often show you problems. I found the `while` with terminating `;` as I started cleaning up your code - then saw someone had posted the answer already. It is important - one day you will be glad for the advice.

Comment: Take a look at the formatted code: the problem is now staring you in the face! Also - see that your "time for a walk; took N steps" lines don't need repeating - it's only the "Jail" vs "Home" bit of string that changes depending on whether `total` is 0 or 10. Again this is much easier to see / appreciate when the code is nicely aligned. Did I mention it's a good idea?

Answer (score 5):

`;` after `while` terminates your loop. So, remove the semicolon `;` after the while statement:

```
while (x > 0);// remove semicolon  ;
```

As your first `while` loop terminated, the value `total`, `steps` don't get changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code has an INFINITE loop

```
do { 
    steps = (int) (Math.random() * (10 +  10) - 10); 
    total += steps;
    x = x-1;
} while (total != 0 || total != 10);
```

Here suppose your `total = 0` then `total != 10` gets satisfied so loop will be continued and in case your `total = 10` then `total != 0` gets satisfied again loop continued **"YOU HAVE USED `||` OPERATOR"**.
You should use `&&` like this

```
    do { 
       steps = (int) (Math.random() * (10 +  10) - 10); 
       total += steps;
       x = x-1;
    } while (total != 0 && total != 10);
```

NOTE : Considering your logic of loop is as you want.